# Seq2Seq Neural Machine Translation step for aligning right to left languages with English (Or any LTR language)

Tags: python, nlp, machine-translation, farsi

I've so far worked with left to right languages and NLTK worked fine for tokenization. But while working on a research paper focused on several languages including RTL languages, the normal procedure has been giving me completely inaccurate translations. Could anyone please let me know what is the norm in neural machine translation when working with languages like Persian or Hebrew?

I've tried following the steps mentioned in [nmt with attention](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/tutorials/nmt_with_attention.ipynb?hl=ja#scrollTo=chTF5N885F0P), where I changed the two regex to fit the Farsi and Urdu scripts along with other languages and seperating the punctuations,

```
def lowerSplitPunct(text):
  # Split accented characters.
  text = tf_text.normalize_utf8(text, 'NFKC')
  text = tf.strings.lower(text)
  # Keep space, a to z, and select punctuation.
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '[^\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF\u200C\u200F\u0980-\u09FFa-z۔؟،«»।ا.?!,]', '')
  # Add spaces around punctuation.
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '[۔؟،«»ا।.?!,]', r' \0 ')
  # Strip whitespace.
  text = tf.strings.strip(text)

  text = tf.strings.join(['[START]', text, '[END]'], separator=' ')
  return text
```

and it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What is the size of data, how many sentences do you use for training? Most likely, this is the main issue as Persian is a low-resource language. Also, you are using word-level tokenization, which is fine; however, subword tokenization, e.g. BPE or unigram model should be better, check out SentencePiece.

Comment: The actual data size was pretty small, around 10k sentences. I augmented it by scraping Wikipedia and a few local newsportals to get only the relevant information and translated to the target languages using Gtranslate. The final dataset has ~30k sentences. 
Well, I've yet to try the Sentencepiece tokenization. Will see if it works

Comment: Is this forward-translation or back-translation? Back-teanslation is better. Also, you can find more parallel data on OPUS; you have to filter it, though.

Comment: I used back translataion to get the additional data. 
Well, truth be told, I'm a bit hesitant to use large corpus from external sources as it will eventually affect the research. The datasets I've collected only have movie subs with conversational dialogues and the model doesn't even translate the lines that are inside the corpus. If the size of the dataset is the issue, maybe I'll have to collect more articles.

Comment: Update: Adding more data and sentencepiece tokenization did not help.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017922/610569 for Persian. For Hebrew, try https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~elhadad/nlpproj/hebtokenizer.py